# Frequency of 8254 Timer

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, x86-16

I am new to assembly language. I Want to Know **what is the actual frequency of timer chip 8254.**

I gone through the internet and found many different answers like maximum frequency is 8 MHz, 1.1 MHz ,etc.,

```
 Which one is right?
```

Comment: The chip itself may have had a max. frequency of about 8 MHz; but when IBM decided to use the chip in the first PCs they chose to use a slower frequency instead to avoid adding an extra oscillator for it (to reduce costs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8253) on 8253 and 8254 timing chips seems to imply that the answser to your question is 1.1 MHz:

> The timer that is used by the system on x86 PCs is Channel 0, and its clock ticks at a theoretical value of 1193181.8181... Hz, i.e. one third of the NTSC color subcarrier frequency, which comes from dividing the system clock (14.31818 MHz) by 12.

The Wikipedia page implies that the chip had a frequency which is a multiple of the NTSC color subcarrier frequency of 3.6 MHz.  I can argue against 8 MHz being the timing frequency because it is *not*  a multiple of 8 MHz (8 / 3.6 = 2.2).

Comment: Thanks for sharing knowledge @ Tim